# dynamic output to single file name in ADF Data Flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a data flow that converts excel files into a csv file and doing some data transformation in between. Is it possible that the filename of the output (sink file) be the same as the input (source file)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the filename as parameter to the dataflow and use it in the option "Output to single file"